# Board and Card games chess questions

Tags: discussion, migration

In the 'Board and Card Games' exchange, I have noticed that there are numerous chess questions. Mostly, they're about variants, or a mate-in-n[longest I've seen is 2]. Should these be migrated over to this site, or should they be left there?

Comment: There are also some on Puzzling, so I guess chess is REAL popular everywhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @HerbWolfe says, questions older than 60 days **cannot** be migrated, as this footnote to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) on migration says:

> <sup>1</sup> After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, *very* rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.

Answer (score 5):

Leave them there. They are on-topic there, so there is no need to migrate them. They also have poker questions, and those don't get migrated to poker.se. There are several subjects that are equally on-topic on multiple Stacks.